# Disk method around vertical line

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

> Set up an integral to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region from x=1 to x=2 about the line x = 3 using the disk method. Do not evaluate the integral. Your answer should not contain absolute value signs. (hint: the inverse function of $e^{ax}$ is $\frac{lnx}{a}$ and the inverse function of ln(ax) is $\frac{e^x}{a}$.)

[Here is a graph of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIaYg.png)

With a = 48, my two equations that make the region are ln(48x) (top) and $e^{-48x}$ (bottom). My initial approach was to split the area into three integrals, ln(48) to ln(96), $e^{-48}$ to ln(48), and $e^{-96}$ to $e^{-48}$. Now, I don't know what to put in the integrands.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let start from the easiest, for the region from $y=e^{-48}$ to $y=\ln(48)$, can you write down the outer and inner radii of the disks? For the other two regions, the outer radii of the disks varies for different $y$. Can you represent the outer radii in terms of $y$ using the inverse function hint?

Comment: More context: [a random user asked this yesterday and deleted their question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3946392/89922), and this question might be an assignment.

Comment: I already wrote out the outer and inner radii in the question and I need to verify if that is correct... So is it?

Comment: The edit looks right to me.

Comment: So the equation I have now is correct?

Comment: The edit looks correct to me. A tiny suggestion, using $y$ instead of $x$ as the dummy variable in the integrals may be more readable, because the disks are stacked on the $y$ direction and each disk thickness is $dy$.

Comment: Yeah, I know but the question's hint has the inverses in terms of x, so I wrote my answer based on that. I did not write the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Here's the answer:

$$\pi\int_{\ln48}^{\ln96}\left(\left(3-\frac{e^x}{48}\right)^2-1\right)dx+\pi\int_{e^{-48}}^{\ln48}(2^2-1)dx+\pi\int_{e^{-96}}^{e^{-48}}\left(\left(3-\frac{\ln x}{48}\right)^2-1\right)dx$$